# How can I rename package name without getting any errors/conflicts, if using the android tools to do it

Tags: android, eclipse, package, rename, provider

I renamed the project's package name of an app I made so that I could make another one from the base of the previous one. I used Android tools -> Rename Package Name. No errors found. I did clean the project before proceeding to the next step: opening the new app. However, it force closed on start. But if I had my previous base app on the phone, I couldn't even install the new app: Installation error: `INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER`. So it has to be something with the provider not likeing the new package name. I did debug (which im not sure how to use) and it pointed to the Info.java in the provider package.

Im not sure what to do... I would really like to rename the package name.

Comment: Did you perform a full uninstall of the app, then try installing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the package name of the content provider included in your application. I assume you are trying to build an existing app from the source (Google's app / Some open-source app / Your app) that contains a content provider. If you have multiple packages try renaming all of it or just the one that contains the content provider.

You will also have to make sure that the rename is consistent with you `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: Do I need to change the package name of my provider?
I thought changing package names of src files is not needed when it comes to changing package file of the whole app.
And yes, "my app" was not made by me.

Comment: Changing the package name is sufficient most of the time, but when you have conflicting components, such as broadcast receivers, content providers and services, it is advisable to avoid namespace collisions.